# Kerbal Space Program in Linux Does not Display Properly

Tags: games, intel-graphics, steam, intel

I have played Kerbal Space Program on this exact same computer previously using an older version of Ubuntu with no problems. Now when I try to play, the game does not show backdrops. (Anything that doesn't move)

[image]

The game does not look like this until I get to this part. The menu and the building selector all looks normal.

I have an ASUS U56E and I am running the newest version Ubuntu. I am also obviously using the Integrated Intel Graphics. (Fully Updated)

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into [KSP bug #7493](http://bugs.kerbalspaceprogram.com/issues/7493) or something similar. Try running with `-gforce-glcore33`.